# Python 3 Mutex Equivalent

Tags: python, socket.io

I have a SocketIO client running with Python 3.6.6. On specific events this client interacts with some custom hardware attached to a Raspberry Pi; these operations can block for seconds at a time and, most importantly: *only one operation can run at any one time*.

My first thought would be to use a mutex lock around the operation, however I've seen that mutexes in Python are [deprecated since v2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html). Does there exist a similar feature in Python 3.6.6+? Or is this something I'm going to have to implement manually?

I have this relatively simple solution, but I'm wondering if there's a way that's baked into the Python standard lib?

```
class STM32L0Namespace(socketio.ClientNamespace):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._mutex_lock = False

    def on_get_unique_id(self, data):
        if not self._mutex_lock:
            self._mutex_lock = True

            # Do some blocking, exclusive operation here

            self._mutex_lock = False   
        else:
            raise MutexLockedError
```

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up writing a mutex decorator. Maybe somebody will find this useful in the future!

```
class MutexLockedError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, func):
        # Handle exception here


class STM32L0Namespace(socketio.ClientNamespace):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._mutex_lock = False

    def _mutex(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            res = None

            try:
                if not self._mutex_lock:
                    self._mutex_lock = True

                    res = func(self, *args, **kwargs)             

                    self._mutex_lock = False
                else:
                    raise MutexLockedError(wrapper.__name__)
            except MutexLockedError as e:
                pass

            if res is not None:
                return res

        return wrapper

    @_mutex
    def on_get_unique_id(self, data):
        # Everything in this function is wrapped inside try/except MutexLockedError
```